# Need app to convert audio files

Tags: sound, soundconverter

Newbie here. I'm about to dump Windows 10 and install Ubuntu, but there's just one Windows app I find indispensable: EZ CD Extractor, for converting between various audio file formats. It will also convert a few video formats to mp3. I suspect it will run with Virtual Box or VMware, but I need to have a Linux app ready in case things don't work out. Any suggestions? I would prefer a GUI for this purpose.

Comment: Welcome! VLC allows to convert video and audio.

Comment: Audacity https://www.audacityteam.org/ also does audio conversion as well as editing, and like VLC, is Open Source. Both are available for Windows and Ubuntu. And, you may also use http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com for these kinds of questions.

Comment: This seems like an easy question for Ubuntu Software. Several excellent options, with and without GUI, are in there. You can, of course, try all of them in the Ubuntu LiveUSB's "Try Ubuntu" environment.

Answer (score 0):

Late reply, but in case anyone else is looking this still applies for Ubuntu 22.04. SoundKonverter (with a "K") seems to work well, soundconverter (with a "c") fails on some of the same files.